# C# Azure Function Nested JSON data POST

Tags: c#, json, post, azure-functions

I want to `POST` a `JSON` data which looks like this:

```
{
 "RequestID": "Req000002",
 "fullfillmenttFactor": 65,
 "ifFlexRequested": "True",
 "isBlind": "True",
 "loc": {
  "user001": 4,
  "user002": 7
 },
 "marketType": "fixedPrice",
 "maxPriceCtpEU": "null"
}
```

Now for the other data, I can do something like this:

```
[BsonElement ("RequestId"), JsonProperty(Required=Required.Always)] 
        public string RequestID { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("FullfillmentFactor"), JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
        public int FullfillmentFactor { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("IfFlexRequested"), JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
        public bool IfFlexRequested { get; set; }
```

But what to do with the `Loc` data?

I can do something like:

```
public class LocationInfo: Document{
[BsonElement("LocInfo"), JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
public int LocInfo { get; set; }
...
}
```

and then in `Loc`:

```
[BsonElement("Loc"), JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
public LocationInfo FullfillmentFactor { get; set; }
```

But here how can I pass multiple values like this:

```
"loc": {
  "user001": 4,
  "user002": 7
 }
```

Comment: as usual when there are "dynamic properties" use dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define loc as a Dictionary for example

```
public Dictionary<string,int> loc { get; set; }
```